# Connecting Microphone (Shure sm58) to Avid Mbox

Tags: microphone, interface, avid, mbox

My question is very basic and simple - is the cable XlR-TRS on end able to connect my microphone to Avid Mbox? For now it’s not working, but I’m not sure if that’s my fault and I didn’t set up mbox control panel right or if it’s the cable. I was told in a store that since mbox uses combo inputs it should work, but now when I check Avid manual it says that only XLR cable works? Or am I misunderstanding something?

(Sorry for bad grammar, English is not my native language. Also - I know it’s probably very basic stuff, but I’m just beginning and not sure where to look for valuable info)

Answer (score 2):

Did you check the manual, see snippet below. A SM58 is a dynamic microphone and needs to be connected at microphone level. 
You will need a XLR-XLR cable.

Mic/Line Inputs
Each analog source input channel provides combination XLR/TRS on the rear panel. These balanced/unbalanced analog audio inputs sup- port the following input levels:
• Mic (microphone) for XLR inputs
• Line (TRS) for line level signals on TRS or TS
inputs